# DNSMasq reporting "TOo few Arguments"

Tags: raspbian-buster, dns, raspberry-pi-desktop

I'm trying to set up a Raspbian X86 server as a DNSMasq host.

I've got it configured but I get a error on startup, "Too few arguments."

it seems to start up "fairly" normally, but I'm assuming this is going to cause me an error, long term.  It gives no other info than this.

This is the contents of my dnsmasq.conf file:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
interface=eth0
ipset=/yahoo.com/google.com/vpn,search
expand-hosts
domain=local
dhcp-range=172.16.10.0,172.16.255.254,255.255.0.0,8h
dhcp-option=option:router,172.16.0.1
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
dhcp-option=vendor:MSFT,2,1i
dhcp-option=vendor:Etherboot,60,"Etherboot"
dhcp-lease-max=5000
dhcp-authoritative
cache-size=9999
bogus-nxdomain=64.94.110.11
dhcp-mac=set:client_is_a_pi,B8:27:EB:*:*:*
dhcp-reply-delay=tag:client_is_a_pi,2
```

I've removed dhcpcd from the system (thinking it might be part of the conflict).

I've configured the /etc/network/interfaces file to be :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.0.3
gateway 172.16.0.1
network 16
```

Network comes up fine.  With static address.  The machine does have multiple NIC cards in it, but only one is hooked up and has an address.

Thoughts on what this error means??

Comment: `Raspbian X86` so is this an Intel based computer running Debian with Raspberry Pi desktop?

Comment: Yes.  It behaves really no different than Raspberry Pi.  And I've seen the same message on the Raspberry Pi clients.  When I reset the dhcp lease and renew it, I get the error.  I'm thinking it's in some other related subsystem, but can't narrow it down with such a vague msg.

Comment: Raspbian has an X86 build as well as the ARM one for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: No, Raspbian is only available for ARM. The x86 version is 'Raspberry Pi Desktop for PC and Mac' and is NOT a version of Raspbian.

Comment: This is a minor quibble, and doesn't do anything to help address the question.  Yes, the PC version doesn't have GPIO support.  But if you read the various blogs from the Raspberry Pi foundation, they've ported the rest.    IN ANY CASE -- This problem occurs on Raspberry Pi's AND the Raspberry Pi Desktop X86 machine.  The error is identical.

Comment: Closest things to an answer seem to be here: 
https://www.mail-archive.com/dnsmasq-discuss@lists.thekelleys.org.uk/msg15398.html
https://www.mail-archive.com/dnsmasq-discuss@lists.thekelleys.org.uk/msg15399.html
I agree, it seems someone improved the 
 /etc/init.d/dnsmasq 
startup script to prevent this error and succeeded, but the version distributed with Raspberry Pi OS has not taken on those changes.